# Resizing attribute table on QGIS print layout

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, print-composer

I have a attribute table which I want to print using the layout composer. From here I have the following questions:

1. How to resize the columns in the print layout?
2. How do I set the horizontal alignment to center?

This is what I have tried to set the width/align and it doesn't work:

```
table = QgsLayoutItemAttributeTable(layout)
table.setVectorLayer(layer)
for coluna in table.columns():
    coluna.setHAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
    coluna.setWidth(150)
table.setUseConditionalStyling(True)
table.setHeaderMode(QgsLayoutTable.NoHeaders)
```

Answer (score 7):

- Assign `table.columns()` to a variable

  ```
  columns = table.columns()
  ```
- Make changes

  ```
  for column in columns:
      column.setHAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
      column.setWidth(150.0)
  ```
- Use `setColumns`

  ```
  table.setColumns(columns)
  layout.refresh()
  ```

---

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
projectLayoutManager = project.layoutManager()
layout = projectLayoutManager.layoutByName('layout_name')

layer = project.mapLayersByName('your_layer_name')[0]
table = layout.itemById('attribute_table_id').multiFrame()

columns = table.columns()
for column in columns:
    column.setHAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
    column.setWidth(150.0)

table.setColumns(columns)

layout.refresh()
```

Answer (score 6):

Adapting from [Ben's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/384937/16141), do the following:

- Clone the table's columns.
- Modify them on the properties of interest (example, 'width' and 'horizonal alignment').
- Set the new and modified columns.

```
table = QgsLayoutItemAttributeTable(layout)
table.setVectorLayer(layer)
#Retrieve layout table columns
cols = table.columns()
#Construct a new list containing cloned QgsLayoutTableColumn objects
new_cols = [col.clone() for col in cols]
#Iterate the cloned columns and use QgsLayoutTableColumn' methods to set width and alignment
for i, cloned_col in enumerate(new_cols):
    cloned_col.setWidth(150)
    cloned_col.setHAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)    
#Set 'table' columns from the list of cloned and modified column objects
table.setColumns(new_cols)
table.refresh()
```